# In Whitehack, how does character level interact with the possible strength of miracles?

Tags: whitehack

I'm reading *Whitehack* 1.7.  On p.4, when talking about the HP cost of miracles for wise characters, the author says "...character level [is] an upper limit."  But then there are examples and instructions to let the player roll for the cost of higher level miracles.  (Though miracles don't actually *have* levels.)  So I'm generally not getting the way these factors sort out.

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hit the author, Christian Mehrstam, up for answers.  He wrote:

> A preset HP cost represents safe magic, like "ok, that is pretty standard -- it will cost you 3 HP". The character's level is the upper HP cost limit for such magic. A varying HP cost is for magic that is too powerful for the character to cast safely, like "ok, that is more magic than you can safely handle at this level -- you shall have to roll 2d6 for the HP cost".

So, any given application of a miracle has a HP cost, set by the referee.  If that amount is greater than the wise character's level, then the ref either tells them *no* or sets some higher, riskier, variable HP cost.